# Using a DLL with a Web Service

Tags: web-services, iis, dll, vb6, oracle-manageddataaccess

I'm working with an older webservice and updating it to coincide with our new system. The previous system using SSMS for databases while the new system is using Oracle databases.

The web service is written in VB (potentially VB6) and ran on IIS to a custom built UI. I'm just looking to update it to look for the correct fields and use the correct query for the new Oracle DBs.

The problem I'm running into is that Microsoft has deprecated the Oracle classes, so trying to use classes like OracleCommand and OracleConnection won't work. Instead, we are opting for an Oracle DLL, specifically Oracle.ManagedData.Access but with IIS compiling the VB code on run, it doesn't find the DLL and causes an error.

Any suggestions on how to get a DLL into the ISS compiler at runtime?

The error I am getting is a Compiler Error.

"Compilation Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'OracleCommand' is not defined."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the error? VB script or VB.NET? IIS does not compile anything at runtime. More data is needed before anyone can try and help you.

Comment: I'm getting a compilation error.


"Compilation Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'OracleCommand' is not defined."

Comment: Something funky going on, because that's a VB.Net or C# CIL compiler message.  So this can't be VB6 or VBScript.